# How does Array.Sort(array, comparison<t>) execute?

Tags: arrays, sorting, delegates

I want to sort numbers, available as string array. After some look up, following was useful.

```
Array.Sort<T> Method (T[], Comparison<T>)
```

But, I want to understand the execution of the comparison function.

- Does the Comparison function override the Sort method implementation or it is called 'n' times after the Sort method is done executing or it will replace some function 'x' with the delegate function passed?
- Where are we getting the values of 2 parameters that we have in our comparison function?

**Example**

```
       Array.Sort(unsorted, (left, right) => {
            if (left.Length != right.Length)
            {
                return left.Length - right.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.CompareOrdinal(left, right);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the Comparison function override the Sort method implementation
>   or it is called 'n' times after the Sort method is done executing or
>   it will replace some function 'x' with the delegate function passed?

The Comparison method will be used to compare elements while sorting. The Sort algorithm will work as it did (InsertionSort or QuickSort). It is a custom comparison that you might require.

> Where are we getting the values of 2 parameters that we have in our
>   comparison function?

The two values to be compared will be picked in the sorting algorithm as per the iteration.

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Think about this People, and you can compare them by name:

```
public class Person
{
   string name;

   public static int CompareByName(Person person1, Person person2)
   { 
      return String.Compare(person1.Name, person2.Name);
   }

}
```

The method `CompareByName(Person person1, Person person2)` fit with the definition of `Comparison<T>`, because the definition is that "Represents the method that compares two objects of the same type." 
 So now, with all of that in mind, you could sort an array of person by name, be cause in the method `Array.Sort<T> Method (T[], Comparison<T>)` you can replace every ocurrence of `T` type with the `Person` type, as result:

```
Array.Sort<Person> Method (T[], Comparison<Person>)
```

So for example you have:

```
Person[] people = {p1,p2,p3...} (where p1,p2,p3... are `Person` type)
```

You can do:

```
Array.Sort(people, Person.CompareByName);
```

And that's it... :)